# Possible more efficient alternative?

Tags: python, django

Is is possible to make this function more efficient and possibly more readable?

In addition, Am I doing this right? I mean, it works, but would it be better to do a complex query (with annotations) or a simple query and then process the result with a "pure python" code-block?

Here is the snippet:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        #Creates a list of dictionaries with the group name and role name
        roles = [{'group': group.name, 'role': role.name} for group in form.cleaned_data['groups'] for role in group.groupextended.role.all()]
        roles = sorted(roles, key=lambda k: k['role'])
        #Groups by the role name
        for role, group in itertools.groupby(roles, key=lambda k: k['role']):
            group_list = list(group)
            #Check if the role is in more of one group associated to the user
            if len(group_list) > 1:
                raise Exception('Exception test: {0}, {1}, {2}'.format(role, obj.username, group_list))

        super(UserExtendedAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you want to go to CodeReview

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do.